# Iterate JSON with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I have JSON content in a file called "json.json":

```
{
    "ENAX-BRANCHESM-10" :
    {
        "repo":"test-ASO",
        "PATH":"/tmp/pruebaAlvaro",
        "ARTEFACTOS":"enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0.jar,enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-sn.jar,enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-facade.jar",
        "uri":"http://server:8081/artifactory/test-ASO",
        "created":"A705663"

    },
    "QZQP-QZQPMAN-16" : {
        "repo": "test-ASO",
        "PATH": "/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2",
        "ARTEFACTOS": "qzqp_manageApp.jar,qzqp_manageApp-sn.jar,qzqp_manageApp-facade.jar",
        "uri": "http://server:8081/artifactory/test-ASO",
        "created": "A705663"
    }
}
```

and I tried to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

fichero = File.read("./json.json")
parseo = JSON.parse(fichero)
valores = parseo.map { |_, v| { v[:PATH] => v[:ARTEFACTOS].split(',') } }
puts valores
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
pruebas.rb:11: private method `split' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `map'
        from pruebas.rb:11:in `each'
        from pruebas.rb:11:in `map'
        from pruebas.rb:11
```

My question is, how do I get this output from the JSON?

```
/tmp/pruebaAlvaro
enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro 
enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-sn.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro
enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-facade.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2 
qzqp_manageApp.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2
qzqp_manageApp-sn.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2
qzqp_manageApp-facade.jar
```

The contents of the `parseo` variable are:

```
QZQP-QZQPMAN-16createdA705663repotest-ASOurihttp://server:8081/artifactory/test-ASOARTEFACTOSqzqp_manageApp.jar,qzqp_manageApp-sn.jar,qzqp_manageApp-facade.jarPATH/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2ENAX-BRANCHESM-10createdA705663repotest-ASOurihttp://server:8081/artifactory/test-ASOARTEFACTOSenax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0.jar,enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-sn.jar,enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-facade.jarPATH/tmp/pruebaAlvaro
```

Is this the right output? Maybe I'm getting that error because the `parseo.map` expects a different content and fails? What can I do?

Comment: This question is identical to one you asked 2 hours prior. Don't do that. You can't expect instant responses as people answering are spread around the world and work on answering in their spare time. As is, this is a duplicate of your other question (albeit slightly reworded and with a bit more information) and I'm marking it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myhash = Hash.new
valores = parseo.map { |_, v| myhash[v["PATH"]] = v["ARTEFACTOS"].split(',') }
puts myhash

#output:

{"/tmp/pruebaAlvaro"=>["enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0.jar", "enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-sn.jar", "enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-facade.jar"]}
{"/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2"=>["qzqp_manageApp.jar", "qzqp_manageApp-sn.jar", "qzqp_manageApp-facade.jar"]}
```

Now if you wanted to access any specific "PATH" then can do like:

```
> myhash["/tmp/pruebaAlvaro"]
#=> ['enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0.jar', 'enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-sn.jar', 'enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-facade.jar']
```

Sorry I just noticed your expected output:

```
myhash.each do |k,v|
  v.each do |value|
    puts k
    puts value
    puts # to drop a blank line
  end
end
#output:
/tmp/pruebaAlvaro
enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro
enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-sn.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro
enax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-facade.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2
qzqp_manageApp.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2
qzqp_manageApp-sn.jar

/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2
qzqp_manageApp-facade.jar
```

Comment: Thank you Gagan, I'm getting this output with your solution:
`/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2qzqp_manageApp.jarqzqp_manageApp-sn.jarqzqp_manageApp-facade.jar
/tmp/pruebaAlvaroenax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0.jarenax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-sn.jarenax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-facade.jar
`

BTW I'm using ruby 1.8.7, is it too old to perform what I want?

Comment: @AlvaroGomezFolgado : I have updated my answer please check now

Comment: @AlvaroGomezFolgado : I have updated my answer with your expected output:

Comment: YAY! You nailed it, thank you for all your efforts @Gagan Gami

Comment: I tried your solution with putting several similar entries and it seems the piece of code `valores = parseo.map { |_, v| { v[:PATH] => v[:ARTEFACTOS].split(',') } }` behaves randomly by ignoring some values, I tried to modify that code but all that I get are syntax errors

Comment: @AlvaroGomezFolgado : can you provide me your input datas? paste it here http://pastie.org/ and generate a link

Comment: here is the data:

[link](http://pastie.org/private/zmdvfvidt5rnk235ymp2w)

Comment: I've created another pastie with the full contents of the code and the output it produces after loading the data given in the previous pastie [code+output](http://pastie.org/private/6imooxhysoifw26eyhrd4a)  as you can see the output gives 11 pairs of path,artefacto instead of the 13 expected

Comment: @AlvaroGomezFolgado : This will work for you http://pastie.org/private/s3btntlh30quittbnuo1ga

Comment: I modified your code to achieve what I wanted, I removed the line of myhash variable and now I get the desired output [pastie](http://pastie.org/private/87t9hjpajpp1nzdszn12q)

However I really appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a string key by providing a symbol. Instead, pass the string to the `:[]` method instead of a symbol (`v['PATH']` and `v['ARTEFACTOS']`).

Comment: So the code would be?

valores = parseo.map { |_, v| { :[] => :[].split(',') } }

I'm not getting the desired output with that

Comment: No.  
`parseo.map { |_, v| { v['PATH'] => v['ARTEFACTOS'].split(',') } }`

Comment: Great! That helped me a lot! but how can I parse the output to get the desired one? With you solution I get that "values" have this content:

`/tmp/pruebaAlvaroenax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0.jarenax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-sn.jarenax_phoneValidationCX-1.0.0-facade.jar
/tmp/pruebaAlvaro2qzqp_manageApp.jarqzqp_manageApp-sn.jarqzqp_manageApp-facade.jar`

I'm really terrible going through arrays :(